# swiftui edgesIgnoreSafeArea only showing on canvas and not working on actual device

Tags: swiftui

Im using `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` to ignore the safe area on the top. this seems to work, and show the image going over the safe area on the top as expected on the canvas. But when I run this on a iPhone 11 plus simulator or iPhone x device (i also tested on other devices on the simulator) it doesn't seem to ignore the edges.

I have tried excluding:

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

But I need the above so I can use a custom back button.

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading ) {
        Image("user1")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height) / 2) + 50)
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Text("\(userData.username), 30")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                    .padding([.leading,.top])
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                    .background(Color("message-background"))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .padding(.top)
            }.padding(.trailing)
            HStack {
            Text("Singer, London")
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .padding([.leading])
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
            Text("all the bio info will go there all the bio info will go thereall the bio info will go thereall the bio info will go there all the bio info will go there.")
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .padding([.leading])
                .padding(.top)
                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20))
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.bottom,50)
        }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }){
            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .background(Color("message-background"))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .padding(.top,20)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me on the simulator as expected. I just added the Text "This works" to demonstrate it:

[image: Example]

So your problem must be somewhere outside the code which you presented in your question.